# Foreign Char letter replacement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have some foreign characters and their corresponding English chars. My query is to have a function to identify the foreign char and replace with its subsequent English char in a give string as an input to function.

Sample foreign chars and English chars are listed below:

Š   S
Å   A
Ï   I
Û   U
å   a

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you are after English names for the characters, that is an achievable goal, as they all have published names as part of the Unicode standard.

See for example:

http://www.unicode.org/ucd/

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/

Your task then is to simply turn the list of unicode characters into a table with 100,000 or so rows. Unfortunately the names you get will be things like ARABIC LIGATURE LAM WITH MEEM MEDIAL FORM.

On the other hand, if you want to actually translate the meaning, you need to be looking at machine translation software. Both Microsoft and Google have well-known cloud translation offerings and there are several other well-thought of products too.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 'Š S Å A Ï I Û U å a ' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
S S A A I I U U a a
```

---

Reference:

- [SQL Collation Name (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foo56483d24-add7-483d-9b96-c6fda460ddbc.aspx)